# Particularly nice bump function

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Is there a smooth ($C^\infty$) function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \left[ 0, 1 \right]$ such that:

- $f(x) = 1$ iff $x = 0$, $f(x) = 0$ iff $\left\lvert x \right\rvert \geq 1$, and $0 < f(x) < 1$ otherwise;
- Every derivative of $f$ is simultaneously $0$ at $x$ if and only if $x = 0$ or $\left\lvert x \right\rvert \geq 1$;
- $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$;
- $f’(x) > 0$ for $-1 < x < 0$ and $f’(x) < 0$ for $0 < x < 1$; and
- $1 - f(x) = f(1 - x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$?

If not, for which subsets of the above five conditions are there satisfactory functions? I know that the standard bump function $f(x) = e^{1 + 1/(x^2 - 1)}$ satisfies all but the last one of my conditions; what other conditions could I exclude, or is there an extension of one of the standard examples to meet the last criterion as well?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function for something that comes very close to your requirements.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @MartinR does my edit clarify your question?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the resources! Is it better now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similarly as in [Bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) you can define
$$
 F(x)={\begin{cases}e^{-{\frac {1}{x}}}&{\text{if }}x>0,\\0&{\text{if }}x\leq 0,\end{cases}}
$$
and
$$
G(x)={\frac {F(1-x)}{F(x)+F(1-x)}},\qquad x\in \mathbb {R} .
$$

$G$ has all desired properties on $[0, \infty)$ so that
$$
 f(x) = G(|x|)
$$
has all five properties.

Plot created with wxMaxima:

```
F(x) := if x > 0 then exp(-1/x) else 0;
G(x) := F(1-x)/(F(x)+F(1-x));
wxplot2d(G(abs(x)), [x, -1.5, 1.5], same_xy);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A function that fulfill your requirements is the [Rvachëv function](https://oeis.org/A288163) $R(x)$, which is a displaced version of the first lobe of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $F(x)$:

$$R(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\quad |x|\geq 1,\\ F(x+1),\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

It have some nice properties as fulfilling the [Delayed differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation):
$$R'(x)=2\ R(2x+1)-2\ R(2x-1)$$
but also it have some "unfriendly properties" that make it unlikely to have a closed-form formula, since it inherit on $(-1,\ 1)$ the characteristics of the Fabius function, which is "an example of an infinitely differentiable function that is nowhere analytic".

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285939/82135) it is shown a clever formula for approximate it through piecewise polynomials, but as a gross approximation it looks like pretty close to the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,\quad x=0,\\
0,\quad |x|\geq 1,\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
You could see both approximation [here in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dxcruumbw7)

[image: approximations]

*Added later:* I think that $f(x)$ is equivalent to the answer given by @MartinR

Comment: Oh wow that’s a really nice reformulation! This is the sort of thing that makes me wish I could accept multiple answers

Comment: @Mel be carefull about the last property: the Fabius function fullfil it on $0<x<1$ so I am not completely sure if the Ravchëv function stand it on the same domain (I think it do it but I didn't test it): check on the following papers by Juan Arias de Reyna: [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442)] and [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487)]

Comment: okay thanks for the info